# Is there a speed difference in alternative 'if' syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

In PHP you can use this:

```
if ($something) {
  //then bla
}
```

or you can use:

```
if ($something): 
  //then bla
endif;
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Is there any **speed** difference in using the second method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't any difference.
This snippet of code will be "converted" into corresponding "lower-level-one".

Moreover, speed difference is give by - approximately - input and complexity: in that case, input doesn't change and complexity neither